# replacing @mysql_fetch_array for php7 upgrade

Tags: php, php-7

I'm trying to migrate a Wordpress site. My new host uses PHP7, and there's a plugin that calls @mysql_fetch_array which is a function that has been removed from PHP7.

This is the function call within its control loop:

```
while( $row = @mysql_fetch_array( $result) ) {
    $newSlider = array();
    $newSlider['name'] = $row['title'];
    $newSlider['value'] = $row['alias'];
    $toReturn[] = $newSlider;
}
```

I did a print_r of the $result Object, and this was the result:

```
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 2
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 2
    [type] => 0
)
```

Is there a drop-in replacement function for @mysql_fetch_array that works with PHP7?

Comment: Have you checked the manual - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php.  Also IMHO - don't use @!

Comment: you might want to take a look at your workflow, don't go to SO first thing, go to the official documentation of the language you are using first. It takes only 5 seconds to find the replacement of the deprecated mysql_fetch_array, [mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Comment: @NigelRen, that link is where I saw that the function was deprecated. I thought I had tried mysqli_fetch_array, but clearly I didn't since that works. Finally, I don't use @, this code is something I inherited from a Wordpress theme for a client...

Comment: @Jelmergu Sorry, I had already checked the documentation, but I missed it from stupidity. For the record, I appreciate what you're saying and agree.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears the $result has been migrated already to use mysqli.
If this is the case, then the function `mysqli_fetch_array` is a drop in replacement for `mysql_fetch_array`.